# Workaround for "undeclared prefix" error on XElement.Load()

Tags: xml, xelement

I'm pulling the source of a website. I then want to extract a specific part of it. My intention is to do this with LINQ-to-XML.

However, I get errors when I parse the source:

```
XElement source = XElement.Load(reader);
```

The problem seems to be references to namespaces I don't have. I get the error: `'addthis' is an undeclared prefix. Line 130, position 51.` due to this line:

```
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_pill_combo" addthis:url="http://www.foo.com/foo">
```

And if I delete that one, other occur.

**Thing is**, I only care about one piece of this XML file - I don't need to be able to parse the whole file. I just want it in an XElement so I can find that one piece of it. Is there a way for me to hack around the parsing error? And I need a generic solution - I want to parse the file regardless of ANY `undeclared prefix` errors.

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This XML is not valid.

In order to use a namespace prefix (such as `addthis:`), the namespace must be declared, by writing `xmlns:addthis="some URI"`.

In general, you shouldn't parse HTML using an XML parser, since HTML is likely to be invalid XML, for this reason and a number of other reasons (undeclared entities, unescaped JS, unclosed tags).
Instead, use [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex).

Comment: You're right ofcourse, and I feel a bit silly for asking. Thanks for the link, it seems to be what I need.

Answer (score 7):

If you need to do it all in code what you want is something like this:

```cs
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings { NameTable = new NameTable() };
XmlNamespaceManager xmlns = new XmlNamespaceManager(settings.NameTable);
xmlns.AddNamespace("addthis", "");
XmlParserContext context = new XmlParserContext(null, xmlns, "", XmlSpace.Default);
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(text), settings, context);
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(reader);
```

And for any additional prefixes add more of these:

```cs
xmlns.AddNamespace("prefix", "");
```

Comment: Sure wish the declaration of xmlDoc was show. Going to `assume` you're using XDocument.